# Best practice for backing up /data/media?

Tags: backup

Currently, TWRP backups don't include `/data/media`, and this doesn't appear to be on the developers' radar at all ([the issue for it over at GitHub](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/276) is just a bunch of +1s with no official response). Now that we have SELinux to contend with, simply copying the files back and forth is apparently [no longer an option](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/276#issuecomment-116733341), and there are a number of different ways to access `/data/media` throughout the filesystem, each with different effective owners and permissions.

In excruciating detail, how should I approach backing up and restoring `/data/media` so everything is restored exactly as it was and my apps don't have trouble with the resulting permissions?

Comment: Isn't `/data/media` just an alias for `/storage/emulated/0`? Permissions and ownership are always restored with Android .tar archives.

Comment: It's not possible to `dd` **/data/media** since it's recognized as a directory. I've not tried, but I think that you can `dd` **/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata**, instead.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman `dd` is surely a bad idea. It's even worse than TWRP & CWM's default backup method, `tar`. In case you're very wealthy and bought a 128GB phone and you only stored a few files in it, `dd` will still backup the whole partition, block by block, resulting in an image of 128GB in size. Also another serious problem is that you can't `dd` directly onto your computer, so you have to find another 128GB storage on your phone (SD card?) to hold the inage temporarily.

Comment: @iBug Of course it's a bad idea. If it were good, I would've posted an answer. By the way, you can `dd` directly to the computer by means of `adb shell`, so that the final command becomes `adb shell "dd if=partition" > out.img`.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman It still will fail. Root is required to `dd` from `/dev/block`. As often occurs, `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`. I just tested it out. However you can still do it in recovery but what's the point in doing so?

Comment: @iBug Well, one could mount the resulting image as a loop device, for "future" use. In my case, I did it to recover deleted files.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Even in your case for further use, `tar` is still a better choice than `dd`. Also there hasn't been a solution to the storage problem discussed for `dd`'s output image. I vote for `tar`.

Comment: @iBug So do I. Let me upvote your answer, by the way.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, that feature was excluded from TWRP just because toxic minimalists and confused inexperienced users are unable to use TWRP properly, making us power users suffer once again?

Comment: According to [the said GitHub comment by _Dees-Troy,_](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/276#issuecomment-239172861) _“[…] the average TWRP user can't even spell adb.”_ – **Why do us power users have to suffer, just because some amateurs out there have no clue about how to use tools intended for power users?**

Comment: @neverMind9 *"power user"* will simply add bind mount /sdcard -> /storage in twrp.fstab (or adb pull)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend directly copying files from/to `/sdcard`.
The `sdcard` service will handle all the permissions and SELinux contexts for you.
The `/storage/emulated/0`, `/mnt/shell/emulated/0` and `/storage/emulated/legacy` are all shadow reflexes of `/data/media` (typically `/data/media/0`). In the `/init.rc` file you can find out that the `/system/bin/sdcard` is a service that controls all of them, so you can just copy the files in `/storage/emulated/0` with ease. All other directories like `/sdcard` and `/storage/sdcard0` are symbolic links. They don't matter at all.

Comment: But what if I want an 1:1 image of that partition?

Answer (score 0):

I just adb pull /data/media/. media to copy the files to my pc adb directory.  Then I do a TWRP backup everything to sdcard.  Restore from sdcard backup, reboot recovery, then adb push media/. /data/media.  Make certain to wipe sdcard from recovery, not formatted from pc.  Works for me!  Wrong format gives lots of error 255's.